# Tkinter PhotoImage not functioning as should

Tags: python, tkinter

When ever I try to use photoimage in tkinter I get this error

```
  File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 2251, in _create

*(args + self._options(cnf, kw))))

TclError: image "pyimage6" doesn't exist
```

I have used this same method before and even on the same project, am i missing something here?
Here is the code.

```
    self.repca = Canvas(self.rep)
    self.repca.place(relx=0.00,rely=0.00,relheight=1.00,relwidth=1.00)
    self.photo5 = PhotoImage(file='lib/maincanvas.gif')
    self.repca.create_image(310,290, image =photo5)
```

Comment: Just a guess: Could it be that you need to use `self.photo5` in the last line instead of just `photo5`?

Comment: Please show us a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)—a stripped-down, but complete, example that demonstrates the problem—rather than just a random fragment of 4 lines of code that may not even contain the error, and is even less likely to have enough information for us to spot it. Unless it is mixing up `photo5` with `self.photo5` as iCodez pointed out, there is nothing else obviously wrong here, so what do you expect us to do to debug it?